# Access: operation must use an updateable query - query used to run without problems

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

So the most puzzling thing is that this query used to work. While I have added a number of new queries, absolutely no changes have been made to this query, and no changes made to the structures of the two query/table referenced in the query.

```
UPDATE INFORCE 
       INNER JOIN [Transactions] 
               ON INFORCE.[Cert Num] = [Transactions].[Cert Num] 
SET    INFORCE.[Prev Trans] = [INFORCE].[Trans], 
       INFORCE.[Prev Trans Dt] = [INFORCE].[Trans Dt], 
       INFORCE.Trans = [Transactions].[Trans], 
       INFORCE.[Trans Dt] = [Transactions].[Trans Dt], 
       INFORCE.[Count of Trans] = [INFORCE].[Count of Trans] + 1, 
       INFORCE.[Cancel Date] = [Transactions].[Trans Dt], 
       INFORCE.Status = "CAN", 
       INFORCE.Cost = [INFORCE].[Cost] 
                         + [Transactions].[Cost], 
       INFORCE.Tax = [INFORCE].[Tax] 
                     + [Transactions].[Tax], 
       INFORCE.[Last Reporting Month] = 
       [Transactions].[Reporting Month] 
WHERE  [Transactions].Trans = 'CN';
```

I have full read/write access to where this file is saved at. Everything is located within the same accdb file, no links elsewhere.

What went wrong?

EDIT: `[INFORCE]` is a table, `[Transactions]` is a query. The below query which I think is quite similar ran without problems. `[EN Final]` is a Table.

```
UPDATE INFORCE AS inf 
       INNER JOIN [EN Final] AS tr 
               ON inf.[Cert Num] = tr.[Cert Num] 
SET    inf.[Prev Trans] = inf.[Trans], 
       inf.[Prev Trans Dt] = inf.[Trans Dt], 
       inf.Trans = tr.[Trans], 
       inf.[Trans Dt] = tr.[Trans Dt], 
       inf.[Count of Trans] = inf.[Count of Trans] + tr.[Count of Trans], 
       inf.Cost = inf.[Cost] + tr.[Cost], 
       inf.Tax = inf.[Tax] + tr.[Tax], 
       inf.[Last Reporting Month] = tr.[Reporting Month], 
       inf.[Ins Start Date] = tr.[Ins Start Date], 
       inf.[Ins End Date] = tr.[Ins End Date], 
       inf.[Days Insured] = tr.[Days Insured];
```

Comment: Is `[INFORCE]` a View/Query, or is it a Table?

Comment: `[INFORCE]` is a Table

Comment: Has `[Transactions]` changed recently? Like an added GROUP BY or something?

Comment: My goodness! `[Transactions]` went from referencing a Table to a Query, which eventually does link to a Query with a GROUP BY. I've changed so that `[Transactions]` now read from a Table and the `UPDATE` now works. I'm still quite confused as to why this happened, but thank you so much JNevill.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the culprit! I also have no idea why Access cares about such a thing. Access just doin' Access, I suppose.